# How To - Azure background task

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have a low priority workload that I want to run in Azure.

Essentially it's a C# console application that fires off a few REST web requests to gather market data and stores it in a local database. The job should run periodically, at least once per week.

I'm already using Azure so prefer to move the workload there. What's the best way to do this i.e. minimise my cost. Should I use Azure Batch, Azure WebJobs, VM's? Any recommendations?

Comment: Any update?If you feel my answer is useful /helpful.Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.

Comment: @Brando: Done. I'm still learning this thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Essentially it's a C# console application that fires off a few REST web requests to gather market data and stores it in a local database. The job should run periodically, at least once per week.

According to your description, I suggest you could choose [azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) or [azure webjobs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki)(I suggest you choose azure function, because you just need copy your codes from local to azure portal.).

> Azure Functions is a solution for easily running small pieces of code, or "functions," in the cloud. You can write just the code you need for the problem at hand, without worrying about a whole application or the infrastructure to run it. Functions can make development even more productive, and you can use your development language of choice, such as C#, F#, Node.js, Python, or PHP. Pay only for the time your code runs and trust Azure to scale as needed. Azure Functions lets you develop serverless applications on Microsoft Azure.

Both of them contains the timer trigger which could help you easily fired the workload to run your codes.

Besides, these two services are very cheap.

Azure function pricing:

[image]

Azure web app(azure function could also run in the app service plan)

[image]

More details about how to use azure function timer trigger, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer).

Comment: Thanks heaps. I'll check out Azure Functions.